# Punteros a función incompatibles, llamadas compatibles

Tags: c++, template, puntero-a-función

#### Explicación.

Dispongo de una lista de objetos que encapsulan un puntero a función (PaF). Todas las funciones tienen el mismo retorno (`void`) pero parámetros arbitrarios, por ello el objeto que encapsula el PaF tiene una clase base común:

```
// Clase base...
struct comodin{};

template <typename ... PARAMETROS>
struct callback : public comodin
{
    // Atajo al tipo de la funcion encapsulada.
    using funcion_t = void(*)(PARAMETROS ...);
    // Constructor.
    callback(funcion_t pf) : puntero{pf} {}
    // Operador de llamada.
    void operator()(PARAMETROS ...parametros) { return puntero(parametros ...); }

private:
    // Funcion encapsulada.
    funcion_t puntero;
};
```

Dado que el objeto `callback` hereda de `comodin`, puedo almacenar diferentes `callback` en un mismo contenedor siempre y cuando sea mediante un puntero a `comodin`:

```
using lista_callbacks = std::list<comodin *>;
```

Y así, crear una colección de objetos `callback` que encapsulen funciones con parametros arbitrarios<sup>1</sup>:

```
void v() { std::cout << "v" << '\n'; };
void vi(int a) { std::cout << "vi" << a << '\n'; };
void vii(int a, int b) { std::cout << "vii" << a << b << '\n'; };
void viii(int a, int b, int c) { std::cout << "viii" << a << b << c << '\n'; };
void viiii(int a, int b, int c, int d) { std::cout << "viiii" << a << b << c << d << '\n'; };
void x(int,char,float,double,long,short) { std::cout << "x" << '\n'; }

using lista_callbacks = std::list<comodin *>;

lista_callbacks callbacks
{
    new callback(v),
    new callback(vi),
    new callback(vii),
    new callback(viii),
    new callback(viiii),
    new callback(x)
};
```

Tengo una función que se encarga de enviar parámetros a la colección de `callbacks`:

```
template <typename ... PARAMETROS>
void envia_parametros(PARAMETROS ... parametros)
{
    // Atajo al tipo de la callback
    using callback_t = callback<PARAMETROS ...>;

    // Recorremos todas las callbacks...
    for (const auto &callback : callbacks)
    {
        /* Convierte cada callback al tipo que coincide con
        los parametros facilitados */
        callback_t &objeto = *static_cast<callback_t *>(callback);
        /* Llama a la funcion encapsulada en la callback
        con los parametros facilitados */
        objeto(parametros ...);
    }
}
```

He observado que puedo invocar el operador de llamada (`operator ()`) de `callback` con colecciones de parámetros incorrectos sin que el compilador se queje de ello ni provocando ningún fallo en tiempo de ejecución:

```
envia_parametros(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

La instrucción anterior muestra:

> ```
> v
> vi1
> vii12
> viii123
> viiii1234
> x
> ```

Puede verse el [[código funcionando aquí]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/oQcnGucwdYa4NS8b).

#### Funciona pero ¿a qué precio?.

**Ningún objeto `callback`** coincide con la firma usada en `envia_parametros` aún así las llamadas se han hecho sin mostrar ningún comportamiento erróneo, yo al menos esperaba una [violación de segmento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violaci%C3%B3n_de_acceso), [corrupción de memoria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corrupci%C3%B3n_de_memoria) o [desbordamiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_mont%C3%ADculo) pero nada de eso ha sucedido. La conversión de tipos de `callback` tampoco ha fallado en ningún caso dentro de `envia_parametros` pese a que sí que falla en otros contextos:

```
callback<> cv(v);
// Error, callback<int> no es convertible a callback<int,int,int,int,int>
auto cast = static_cast<callback<int,int,int,int,int>>(cv);
```

```
void(*PaF)() = v;
// Error, PaF void() no es convertible a PaF void(int,int,int,int,int)
static_cast<void(*)(int,int,int,int,int)>(v)(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
// Error, no se puede llamar a la funcion apuntada con esos parametros
PaF(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

```
v(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);     // Demasiados parametros
vi(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);    // Demasiados parametros
vii(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);   // Demasiados parametros
viii(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);  // Demasiados parametros
viiii(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // Demasiados parametros
x(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);     // Pocos parametros
```

Sospecho que el código hace uso de [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido) pero no encuentro en qué parte del estándar de C++ se indica este tipo de conversiones o llamadas que en el contexto de una funcion plantilla variádica son correctas y fuera de ese contexto no lo son.

#### Pregunta.

Las llamadas que estoy haciendo a las funciones a través del PaF encapsulado en el objeto `callback` ¿Son seguras? (¿Pueden provocar algún fallo en tiempo de ejecución?, Los objetos innecesarios en la llamada a función ¿pueden corromper la pila?).

.

---

<sup>1</sup>Mi caso de uso es diferente: clasifico los `callback` en un mapa según la firma de la función que encapsulan (para evitar llamar PaF con parámetros inadecuados), pero este es un ejemplo simplificado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tiene toda la pinta de ser algo dependiente del compilador. Para verlo vamos a partir de un ejemplo un poco más simplificado:

```
// Clase base...
struct comodin{};

template <typename ... PARAMETROS>
struct callback : public comodin
{
    // Atajo al tipo de la funcion encapsulada.
    using funcion_t = void(*)(PARAMETROS ...);
    // Constructor.
    callback(funcion_t pf) : puntero{pf} {}
    // Operador de llamada.
    void operator()(PARAMETROS ...parametros) { return puntero(parametros ...); }

private:
    // Funcion encapsulada.
    funcion_t puntero;
};

void v(){ std::cout << '\n'; }
void vi(int a){ std::cout << a << '\n'; }
void vii(int a, int b){ std::cout << a << b << '\n'; }

using lista_callbacks = std::list<comodin *>;

lista_callbacks callbacks
{
    new callback(v),
    new callback(vi),
    new callback(vii)
};

template <typename ... PARAMETROS>
void envia_parametros(PARAMETROS ... parametros)
{
    // Atajo al tipo de la callback
    using callback_t = callback<PARAMETROS ...>;

    // Recorremos todas las callbacks...
    for (const auto &callback : callbacks)
    {
        /* Convierte cada callback al tipo que coincide con
        los parametros facilitados */
        callback_t &objeto = *static_cast<callback_t *>(callback);
        /* Llama a la funcion encapsulada en la callback
        con los parametros facilitados */
        objeto(parametros ...);
    }
}

int main()
{
  envia_parametros(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
}
```

Si ahora compilamos con, por ejemplo, clang 3.9.1, obtenemos los siguientes fragmentos en ensamblador:

```
v():                                  # @v()
    push    rax
    mov     byte ptr [rsp + 7], 10
    lea     rsi, [rsp + 7]
    mov     edi, std::cout
    mov     edx, 1
    call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
    pop     rax
    ret

vi(int):                                 # @vi(int)
    push    rax
    mov     eax, edi
    mov     edi, std::cout
    mov     esi, eax
    call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
    mov     byte ptr [rsp + 7], 10
    lea     rsi, [rsp + 7]
    mov     edx, 1
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
    pop     rax
    ret

vii(int, int):                               # @vii(int, int)
    push    rbx
    sub     rsp, 16
    mov     ebx, esi
    mov     eax, edi
    mov     edi, std::cout
    mov     esi, eax
    call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
    mov     rdi, rax
    mov     esi, ebx
    call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
    mov     byte ptr [rsp + 15], 10
    lea     rsi, [rsp + 15]
    mov     edx, 1
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
    add     rsp, 16
    pop     rbx
    ret
```

Vale, ahí vemos que las funciones están evitando hacer uso de la pila para cargar los parámetros. Todos los parámetros se pasan vía registros. Seguimos:

```
.LBB4_2:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    mov     rax, qword ptr [rbx + 16]
    mov     edi, 1
    mov     esi, 2
    mov     edx, 3
    mov     ecx, 4
    mov     r8d, 5
    call    qword ptr [rax]
    mov     rbx, qword ptr [rbx]
    cmp     rbx, r14
    jne     .LBB4_2
```

Este es el bucle que envía los parámetros a cada función. Como vemos guarda cada parámetro en un registro diferente: `edi`, `esi`, `edx`, `ecx` y `rd8`.

Lo que sucede entonces es que si una función no necesita uno de los parámetros directamente no hace uso del registro correspondiente y listo. Problemas de ejecución en este caso: ninguno.

Ahora... ¿Qué sucede si seguimos jugando? Veamos un nuevo ejemplo. Ahora vamos a modificar ligeramente la función `vii`, dejando el resto del código intacto:

```
void vii(std::string a){ std::cout << a << '\n'; }
```

El nuevo código de `vii`, una vez compilado, se parece a esto:

```
vii(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >): # @vii(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)
    push    rax
    mov     rsi, qword ptr [rdi]
    mov     rdx, qword ptr [rdi + 8]
    mov     edi, std::cout
    call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
    mov     byte ptr [rsp + 7], 10
    lea     rsi, [rsp + 7]
    mov     edx, 1
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
    add     rsp, 8
    ret
```

De aquí me gustaría destacar estas dos líneas:

```
mov     rsi, qword ptr [rdi]
mov     rdx, qword ptr [rdi + 8]
```

Ahora ya el código sí que empieza a comportarse de forma extraña. Lo que está sucediendo en esas dos líneas es que el programa intenta cargar en `rdi` y `rdx` lo que se supoen debería ser el puntero interno del `string` pero cosas de la vida ahí no hay ningún puntero válido.

Si seguimos con las pruebas podemos seguir aflorando problemas:

```
void vii(int,int,int,int,int,int a){ std::cout << a << '\n'; }
```

Ahora lo que debería suceder es que se mostrará un valor aleatorio. Lo comprobamos con el ensamblado:

```
vii(int, int, int, int, int, int):                           # @vii(int, int, int, int, int, int)
    push    rax
    mov     edi, std::cout
    mov     esi, r9d
    call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
    mov     byte ptr [rsp + 7], 10
    lea     rsi, [rsp + 7]
    mov     edx, 1
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
    pop     rax
```

Ahí está:

```
mov     esi, r9d
```

En ningún momento se ha almacenado nada en `r9d`, por lo que el valor que leamos no será más que basura.

¿Y qué sucede si se superan el número de registros?

```
void vii(int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int a){ std::cout << a << '\n'; }
```

En este caso encontramos el siguiente ensamblado:

```
vii(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int):                 # @vii(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int)
    push    rax
    mov     esi, dword ptr [rsp + 88]
    mov     edi, std::cout
    call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
    mov     byte ptr [rsp + 7], 10
    lea     rsi, [rsp + 7]
    mov     edx, 1
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
    pop     rax
    ret
```

Y destacamos la siguiente línea:

```
mov     esi, dword ptr [rsp + 88]
```

`rsp` es el registro que apunta a la pila del programa... ahí está aplicando un offset de 88 bytes para, supuestamente, leer el último parámetro. No hace falta decir que en dicha posición no va a encontrar el valor que espera. ¿Qué puede suceder aqui? A mi se me ocurren dos posibilidades:

- Lee basura
- Intenta leer fuera de la zona de memoria asignada al programa y el SO finaliza el proceso.

**Conclusiones**

> Las llamadas que estoy haciendo a las funciones a través del PaF encapsulado en el objeto callback ¿Son seguras?

Mientras se use un número de argumentos de tal manera que todos se puedan almacenar en registros y que los tipos sean **todos nativos**, las llamadas serán relativamente seguras.

Ahora, en cuanto una función intente recibir una clase, un puntero o una referencia prepárate para lo peor.

> ¿Pueden provocar algún fallo en tiempo de ejecución?

Como vemos, es posible que sí, todo depende del contexto en el que se use y de lo que esperen recibir las funciones.

> ¿pueden corromper la pila?

Depende. Bajo implementaciones como la presentada, las funciones únicamente lanzan operaciones de lectura sobre la pila y no la modifican, por lo que no pueden corromper la pila. Sin embargo no hay que olvidar que algunos compiladores permiten jugar con la forma en que las funciones gestionan los argumentos (`__fastcall`, `__stdcall`, ...) y en estos casos podemos encontrarnos con que las funciones pasan a manipular la pila y eso sí que podría ser un problema.

**Nota final:**

Sí que sería interesante saber por qué el compilador traga con una conversión que no es legal hacerla de forma manual. Aun así yo siempre sugeriría hacer uso de `dynamic_cast` en el caso de polimorfismo. Su coste computacional es actualmente bastante bajo y proporciona la seguridad de que no se van a hacer conversiones no válidas. Para usar `dynamic_cast` correctamente habría que realizar los siguientes cambios:

```
struct comodin{
  virtual ~comodin() = default;
};
```

Para que `vtable` registre una clase como polimórfica (algo necesario para usar `dynamic_cast`) es necesario que la clase base tenga al menos un método virtual... y en estos casos lo más sencillo y recomendable es que declarar virtual el destructor.

Ahora tendríamos dos opciones, o declaramos el operador función como constante o realizamos un `const_cast` (más adelante lo explico). Mientras no haya razones para evitarlo prefiero optar por declarar la función como constante:

```
template <typename ... PARAMETROS>
struct callback : public comodin
{
    void operator()(PARAMETROS ...parametros) const { return puntero(parametros ...); }
};
```

Y ya solo falta meterle mano a la función `envia_parametros`. Para empezar ya no podemos usar `objeto` como una referencia sino que debemos declararlo como un puntero. Si lo mantenemos como referencia nos arriesgamos a un casque seguro cuando `dynamic_cast` nos devuelva un puntero nulo:

```
for (const auto &callback : callbacks)
{
    /* Convierte cada callback al tipo que coincide con
    los parametros facilitados */
    const callback_t *objeto = dynamic_cast<const callback_t*>(callback);

    /* Llama a la funcion encapsulada en la callback
    con los parametros facilitados */
    if( objeto )
     (*objeto)(parametros ...);
}
```

Si no hemos declarado el operador función como constante tendremos que usar un segundo cast para eliminar el modificador `const` del puntero y poder así llamar al operador función:

```
callback_t *objeto = dynamic_cast<callback_t*>(const_cast<comodin*>(callback));
```

Y ya podemos hacer una prueba tonta para ver que funciona:

int main()
  {
    envia_parametros(1);   // vi1
    envia_parametros(2,3); // vii23
  }

Comment: ¿Qué diferencia tendríamos entre `static_cast` y `dynamic_cast` en este contexto? Cualquier conversión de la familia `callback` a `comodin` será siempre posible y en consecuencia cualquier conversión de `callback` de un tipo a otro lo será también ¿no?.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` debería devolver un puntero nulo si los tipos no son compatibles. Este cast comprueba la `vtable` de cada objeto para conocer su jerarquía y si intentas hacer un cast no válido lo detecta y te devuelve un puntero nulo.

Comment: Lo se, y a eso me refiero: cualquier convesión entre `comodin` y (virtualmente) cualquier instancia de la plantilla `callback` será siempre posible.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Me has pillando editando el comentario anterior. échale un ojo

Comment: Voy a hacer unas pruebas al respecto, gracias.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster `dynamic_cast` únicamente se puede usar con conversiones de punteros, ni referencias ni objetos por valor. Y devolverá un puntero nulo si los tipos no están relacionados mediante herencia **para la instancia actual**

Comment: @eferion `dynamic_cast` se puede utilizar para hacer castings entre referencias, pero en vez de devolver una "referencia nula" (cosa que no existe), lanza una excepción de tipo `bad_cast`.

Comment: @Peregring-lk cierto, me expresé mal. Gracias por la corrección