# Compatibilidad en tamaño de punteros-a-función-miembro

Tags: c++, c++11

Tengo una estructura que uso para mantener diversos punteros:

```
class SignalBase {
protected:

  // Para no necesitar diversas instancias de 'std::vector< >'.
  struct Target {
    void *callback;
    void *self;
    void ( Target::*method )( );

    Target( const Target & ) = default;
    Target( void *cb  ) : callback( cb ), self( nullptr ), method( nullptr ) { }
    template< typename T > Target( void *cb, void *s, void ( T::*m )( ) ) : callback( cb ), self( s ), method( reinterpret_cast< void ( Target::* )( ) >( m ) ) { }
  };

  std::vector< Target > m_vector;

  ...
};
```

Podría haber usado una clase plantilla, pero el objetivo es no necesitar una instanciación de `std::vector` para cada combinación de tipos.

Los tipos reales se deciden en otra clase, esta vez si, plantilla. Lo relevante es que:

- `callback` puede ser un puntero a función-no-miembro, un puntero a función-miembro `static`, o un puntero a función lambda **sin captura** ( siempre tendrá un valor `!= nullptr` ).
- `self` es, o bien `nullptr`, o bien un puntero a una instancia de clase (de cualquier tipo, con o sin métodos virtuales).
- `method` es, o bien `nullptr`, o bien un puntero-a-función-miembro de cualquier clase (con o sin métodos virtuales). Lo único seguro es que **no será** un puntero a función-miembro de `Target`.

La asignación de los distintos valores se realiza en funciones plantilla dentro de, a su vez, clases plantilla. Es relativamente compleja. **Pero** en mis pruebas, **todo funciona correctamente**.

La duda principal es:

- ¿ Será siempre `void ( Target::*method )( )` de tamaño suficiente para almacenar **cualquier** puntero-a-función-miembro de **cualquier** clase (con o sin métodos virtuales) ?

Adicionalmente (aunque de esto si estoy bastante seguro):

- ¿ El resto de variables-miembro ( `callback`, `self` ) será siempre de tamaño suficiente para contener sus posibles valores ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿ Será siempre `void ( Target::*method )( )` de tamaño suficiente para almacenar **cualquier** puntero-a-función-miembro de **cualquier** clase (con o sin métodos virtuales) ?

Si, no, puede, a veces, no se. El problema es que [los punteros a funciones miembro son unos extraños animales](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=40713) (traducción mía):

> **Atención**: Este contenido es específico a la manera en que los punteros a funciones miembro están implementados por el compilador Microsoft Visual C++. Otros compiladores podrían hacer las cosas de manera diferente.
>
> Bien, vale, si usas herencia simple, entonces los punteros a funciones miembro son sólo un puntero a l inicio de la función, ya que todas las clases base comparten el mismo puntero “this”:
>
> ```
> class Simple { int s; void S(); };
> class Simple2 : public Simple
> { int s2; void S2(); };
> class Simple3 : public Simple2
> { int s3; void S3(); };
>
> +----------------+
> | +------------+ |
> | | +--------+ | |
> | | | Simple --------> p
> | | +--------+ | |
> | |  Simple2   | |
> | +------------+ |
> |  Simple3       |
> +----------------+
> ```
>
> Dado que todas usan el mismo puntero “this” (p), un puntero a una función miembro de `Simple` puede ser usado como si fuera un puntero a función miembro de `Simple2` sin que sea necesario ningún ajuste.
>
> > El tamaño de un puntero-a-función-miembro de una clase que sólo usa herencia simple es el tamaño de un puntero.
>
> Pero si tienes múltiples clases base, entonces las cosas se ponen interesantes.
>
> ```
> class Base1 { int b1; void B1(); };
> class Base2 { int b2; void B2(); };
> class Derived : public Base1, Base2
> { int d; void D(); };
>
> +-----------+
> | +-------+ |
> | | Base1 ------> p
> | +-------+ |
> | +-------+ |
> | | Base2 ------> q
> | +-------+ |
> |  Derived  |
> +-----------+
> ```
>
> Ahora hay dos posibles punteros “this”. El primero (p) es usado tanto por `Derived` como por `Base1`, pero el segundo (q) es usado por `Base2`.
>
> Un puntero a función miembro de `Base1` puede usarse como puntero a función miembro de `Derived` ya que ambos usan el mismo puntero “this”. Pero un puntero a función miembro de `Base2` no puede usarse tal cual como puntero a función miembro de `Derived`, ya que el puntero “this” necesita ser ajustado.
>
> Hay muchas maneras de resolver esto. Así es como el compilador Visual Studio lo hace:
>
> Un puntero a función miembro de una clase con multi-herencia es en realidad una estructura.
>
> ```
> +-------------------------+
> | Dirección de la función |
> +-------------------------+
> |        Ajustador        |
> +-------------------------+
> ```
>
> El tamaño de un puntero-a-función-miembro de una clase que usa herencia múltiple es el tamaño del puntero mas el tamaño de un `size_t`.

---

En resumen, los punteros a funciones miembro son raros, no se comportan como punteros normales, pueden no tener el tamaño de punteros normales y no se puede asumir que todos los compiladores los gestionen igual. Ergo: No hay respuesta concluyente.

Comment: Es lo que sospechaba, entramos al difuso mundo del `implementation-defined` ... no podré usar un `std::vector< >` :-(

Comment: @Trauma Podrías usar `std::vector` pero tendrías que mejorar la implementación de `Target`. Quizás usar polimorfismo para cubrir las diferentes necesidades de cada tipo de `Target`

Comment: @eferion hace meses discutimos sobre implementaciones de [colecciones de punteros a función](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/49593/2742), la gracia era tener un objeto base (evitando las conversiones a `void`), es fácilmente adaptable a la idea de Trauma.

Comment: Ah vale, que este tema tiene un trasfondo que ignoraba :)

Comment: @eferion no es que ignorases ese trasfondo, es que dicho trasfondo no existía hasta que *me he acordado* de mencionarlo.

Comment: @eferion ¿ Como podría mejorarlo ? Es lo que estaba intentando con la pregunta. Pero, aparte de algún tipo de *puntero genérico a función miembro*, no se me ocurre como hacerlo :-(

Comment: @Trauma en ese ejemplo no hay usos... solo parte de la implementación, tampoco hay requisitos... así es complicado ver si es factible una implementación que te pueda gustar más

Comment: Si, bueno, era solo el código mínimo. Una implementación del concepto de `señales`, que admita *avisar* tanto a una función como a una función-miembro. De momento lo he dejado así, y parece que funciona. Parece que los tamaños de los punteros-a-función-miembro son siempre el mismo, sea cual sea la clase y la función-miembro. Aunque se que eso no está definido en ningún sitio, la lógica dicta que ha de ser así ...

Comment: Mira a ver si [esto](https://wandbox.org/permlink/64dcMEiQuaiELs28) te inspiera @Trauma